# Using tooltip in D3 chord diagram to get value - Error: "property of target undefined"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to create a chord diagram and have the value of each ribbons source and target value as seen be accessible when they are hovered over. I also want to be able to access the index of that value to refer to use the colour.

At the moment I am getting an error of d not being defined whenever I hover over - I'm not sure how to access the values I need.. I don't want to add any other .js libraries if possible.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.group-tick line {
  stroke: #000;
}

.ribbons {
  fill-opacity: 0.67;
}

.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    min-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #6F257F;
    padding: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.5 - 40,
    innerRadius = outerRadius - 30;

var formatValue = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e3);

var chord = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(0.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(d3.range(4))
    .range(["#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223"]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .datum(chord(matrix));

var group = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groups")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
  .enter().append("g");

group.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.index)).darker(); })
    .attr("d", arc);

var groupTick = group.selectAll(".group-tick")
  .data(function(d) { return groupTicks(d, 1e3); })
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-tick")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ") translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)"; });

groupTick.append("line")
    .attr("x2", 6);

groupTick
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value % 5e3 === 0; })
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180) translate(-16)" : null; })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return formatValue(d.value); });

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "ribbons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", ribbon)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      tooltip
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
          .style("display", "inline-block")
          .html(function(d) {
            return (d.target.index) + "Hello";
          });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
      tooltip
          .style("display", "none")
    })
    ;

// Returns an array of tick angles and values for a given group and step.
function groupTicks(d, step) {
  var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, step).map(function(value) {
    return {value: value, angle: value * k + d.startAngle};
  });
}

</script>
```

I'm using the tutorial here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there is no datum associated with your tooltip:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
```

So when you say `tooltip.html(function(d) { ...` there is no datum associated with that element to use.

Instead, try to use the datum associated with the selected chord:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {  // the datum you want
  tooltip
      .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
      .style("display", "inline-block")
      .html(d.target.index + "Hello");
})
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.group-tick line {
  stroke: #000;
}

.ribbons {
  fill-opacity: 0.67;
}

.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    min-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #6F257F;
    padding: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.5 - 40,
    innerRadius = outerRadius - 30;

var formatValue = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e3);

var chord = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(0.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(d3.range(4))
    .range(["#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223"]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .datum(chord(matrix));

var group = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groups")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
  .enter().append("g");

group.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.index)).darker(); })
    .attr("d", arc);

var groupTick = group.selectAll(".group-tick")
  .data(function(d) { return groupTicks(d, 1e3); })
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-tick")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ") translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)"; });

groupTick.append("line")
    .attr("x2", 6);

groupTick
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value % 5e3 === 0; })
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180) translate(-16)" : null; })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return formatValue(d.value); });

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "ribbons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", ribbon)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
      tooltip
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
          .style("display", "inline-block")
          .html(d.target.index + "Hello");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
      tooltip
          .style("display", "none")
    })
    ;

// Returns an array of tick angles and values for a given group and step.
function groupTicks(d, step) {
  var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, step).map(function(value) {
    return {value: value, angle: value * k + d.startAngle};
  });
}

</script>
```